# Could not find the ... dump file, Win32 error 0n87

Tags: windbg

I tried loading a SYS file into WinDbg via File/ Open Crash Dump and it keeps saying

> Could not find the C:\Windows[...]\win32k.sys Dump File, Win32 error 0n87
>
> Invalid parameter

[image: Screenshot]

I checked multiple times with different tools: the file exists. There must be a different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the background, WinDbg shows the command window with additional information. Once you click the "Ok" button, that information disappears, so keep the dialog open.

In your case, it may show something like

```
Loading dump file [C:\Windows\[...]\win32k.sys]
Could not match Dump File signature - invalid file format
Could not open dump file [C:\Windows\[...]\win32k.sys], Win32 error 0n87
Invalid parameter
```

The second line clearly indicates that WinDbg was able to find the file, but still unable to open the file.

If you have a hex editor available, you'll see that WinDbg cannot open SYS files that start with `DCD` (a file format that I don't know in more detail) but will be able to open SYS files that start with `MZ` (the [Portable Executable](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) format).

Thanks to [@magicandre1981](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1466046/magicandre1981) in the comments: Windows compacts files in the WinSXS directory. [lzmsexpand](https://web.archive.org/web/20150626001828/http://www.alex-ionescu.com/lzmsexpand.exe) can uncompress those files.

Comment: when you install a new Update rollup Windows tries to free disk space by compacting the WinSxS folder and here the old RTM bits (14393.**0** is RTM of v1607) are compressed and so no longer valid MZ files

Comment: @magicandre1981: thanks for that information. Is there a tool to un-compress those? `expand` doesn't seem to work. Why is it compressed this way? Whouldn't it be good enough to compress it via NTFS's transparent compression?

Comment: use tool from Alex Ionescu: https://twitter.com/aionescu/status/597520706876801024

Comment: @magicandre1981: awesome. If there's no superuser question about this yet, I could ask one if you like.

Comment: what do you want to ask? about this compression?

Comment: Just about a tool that can decompress them. BTW, that tool does not work for my files: `File does not appear to be a valid DCS 1.0 compressed file`

Comment: ask alex via twitter. maybe the newer win10 builds use a different compression

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to open w32k.sys as dump, it will show the error. point to the correct dump file like filename.dmp

Comment: WinDbg cannot only open .dmp files. Just open a DLL or EXE file and you'll see that it works

Comment: Thomas, I didn't said that windbg just can open DMP files

Comment: Then, why do you suggest to open a DMP file when I want to open a SYS file?